# Telegram API : change Telegram Messenger Group user limits

Tags: android, telegram

I want create android  telegram app with telegram API
, that change Group user limits to 1000!

So is this possible?!

Answer (score 1):

No.

Group chat is limited to 200, as stated [here](https://telegram.org/faq)

> With Telegram, you can send messages, photos, videos and files of any type (doc, zip, mp3, etc), as well as create groups for up to 200 people

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your Question is : Definitely no


But you can upgrade your group to a supergroup that supports up to 1000 members.

And use it

https://telegram.org/blog/supergroups

Good Luck !!!